# RegExp value still not working with .match even though escapeCharacter function is used

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regExp expression which works on regexr.com
/(?<=("))AK\w{0,1}(?=")/g

It will return the value AK from a string version of an array of objects that has been stringified.  However, when I use the escapeStringRegExp function to account for escape characters and then try to use the string.match function, i keep getting null back when I try to console.log.  My code is as follows:

```
const escapeStringRegexp = require("escape-string-regexp");

    const myData = [
{name:"NY", fullName: "New York"}, 
{name: "AK", fullName: "Alaska"}, 
{name: "NJ", fullName: "New Jersey"}
];

const stateJSONString = JSON.stringify(myData);

let myExp = `(?<=("))AK\\w{0,1}(?=")`    //This works on regexr.com (Expected value back is AK)

const escapedString = escapeStringRegexp(myExp);
let outputString = RegExp(escapedString,"g");

const output = stateJSONString.match(outputString)
console.log(output)
```

For the life of me, I dont know why I keep printing a null.  What am I missing here.  I console.logged all the lines before it goes through the match function and it all looks accurate.

```
console.log(myExp)    //Printed (?<=("))AK\w{0,1}(?=") I had to add an extra \ for the \w   
console.log(escapedString)   //Printed \(\?<=\("\)\)AK\\w\{0,1\}\(\?="\)  It caused an extra \\w
console.log(outputString) //Printed /\(\?<=\("\)\)AK\\w\{0,1\}\(\?="\)/g   This is giving me a null
```

I even tried taking the extra `\` out of the `\\w` and it still didnt work.

I eventually want to replace the `AK` with a `variable` which will return me results based on the value passed.  I am stumped on why the hard coded value of `AK` doesnt work.  If someone can assist in helping me on why the hardcoded value doesnt work as well as how to change the above code to account for a variable, it would be much appreciated.

Update:
Also, as far as using JSON parser vs regex.  Im still new to the best and efficient method of parsing.  So basically, imagine that I have a list of 50 states.  On the state field in a form, every time the user types in a letter, it searches my JSON object of states and displays the matching states that start with that letter, hence the regexp string.  I wanted a dynamic way to go through the JSON string with minimal looping so it comes back fast.  I want to use this same process for other types of searches and thought RegExp was the best way.  Any suggestions on the best way to provide the user matching states without looping through the whole JSON object each time the user types in a letter?

Comment: 1.) You should use a JSON parser to parse JSON, not regex. 2.) `{0,1}` should just be written as `?`. 3.) What's the optional `\w` for? Isn't the value you're looking for always just `AK`? 4.) Your output string is escaped so nothing functions as a regex special character, it's just looking for character literals.

Comment: The optional \w is for when i use different values.  AK is just some placeholder text.  I want the regex to have the capability to return all names that start with A or AK.  Basically, partial or full match of 2 letters for State.

Comment: Does Javascript support look behinds?  It seems the main culprit in my regExp even with correct escape characters is the ?<=(") portion